# Stacked Column Highcharts not working in IE 8

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, highcharts

I am using **Jquery version 1.11 and highcharts 4.0.1** in Ruby on Rails Application.

The stacked column high-charts are working fine on all the browsers except in IE8 where its throwing a error "**Object does not support this property or method : eval code, line 1 character 3855** (Jquery.js line 7060 character 5)"

Here is the js code :

```
    <%= javascript_tag do %>
  new Highcharts.Chart({
        chart: {
            renderTo: <%= render_div.to_json.html_safe  %>,
            type: 'column'
            },
            credits: {
               enabled: false
            },
            title: {
                text: <%= ("#{heading} Data Chart").to_json.html_safe %>
            },

            xAxis: {
                categories: <%= graph_months.to_json.html_safe %>
            },
            yAxis: {
                min: 0,
                stackLabels: {
                    enabled: false,
                    style: {
                        fontWeight: 'bold',
                        color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.textColor) || 'gray'
                    }
                }
            },
            tooltip: {
                formatter: function() {
                    return '<b>'+ this.x +'</b><br/>'+
                        this.series.name +': '+ this.y +'<br/>'
                }
            },

            plotOptions: {
                column: {
                    stacking: 'normal',
                    dataLabels: {
                        enabled: true,
                        color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.dataLabelsColor) || 'white',
                        style: {
                            textShadow: '0 0 3px black, 0 0 3px black'
                        },
                        formatter: function() {
                          if (this.y != 0) {
                            return this.y +'%';
                          } else {
                            return null;
                          }
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            series: [{
                name: 'A',
                color: '#003D66',
                data: <%=  a_array.to_json.html_safe%>
            },
            {
                name: 'B',
                color: '#006BB2',
                data: <%= b_array.to_json.html_safe %>
            },
            {
                name: 'C',
                color: '#B2E0FF',
                data: <%= c_array.to_json.html_safe %>
            },
            {
                name: 'D',
                color: '#4DB8FF',
                data: <%= d_array.to_json.html_safe %>
            }           
            ]
        });
<% end %>
```

Comment: You should use older jquery or migration plugion, which supports ie8. http://jquery.com/download/

Comment: Thanks Sebastian. That did work. I downgraded it from jquery version 1.11 to 1.9. Just one more question. Highcharts offcial page mentions jquery 1.4.3 to 1.10x as compatible with highcharts. But even 1.10 was not working. I had to reduce by one more version(ie 1.9) to get it working. Why is it like that?

Comment: The problem, which you has was related with jquery not highcharts, so we cannot be responsible for jquery solutions.